# Custom Gradle plugin can't apply another plugin

Tags: gradle-plugin

I'm trying to implement a Gradle plugin that calls the [OWASP Dependency Check](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-gradle/) task:

```java
public class XPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        project.getBuildscript().getDependencies().add("classpath",
                "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:8.2.1");

        project.apply(action -> {
            action.plugin("org.owasp.dependencycheck");
        });
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

The call `project.apply(...)` gives the following error:

```
Plugin with id 'org.owasp.dependencycheck' not found.
```

How to fix the issue?